# App Crashing in Simulator After Deleting and Re-builiding Entities in Xcode CoreData file (.xcdatamodeld)

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, xcode8

I'm sure this is a rookie mistake but I'm stumped.

I've noticed that when I rename things in Xcode (viewController.swift) after their initial linkage from the main storyboard, I have to dig down into the files and rename them in the under-the-hood code as well.

I've recently been using Core Data and accidentally defined one of the attributes to be an Int instead of a string.  At first, I simply updated the attribute type but that didn't seem to help.  Still crashing.

Then, I deleted all the Entities from the Core Data file (.xcdatamodeld) and now it is crashing every time I'm trying to set the context.  Here's the relevant code:

The relevant code:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

This worked fine until my meddling.  Now it dies on line 2 above.

Quit and opened Xcode.
I've tried doing a Clean and Clean Build Folder.

I'm pretty stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does it crash and what is printed in the console ? Have you tried uninstalling the app ?

Comment: It crashes at the second line, as I stated in the OP.  I shut down the Simulator.  I also deleted the app from the simulator.

Comment: Also, I tried to upload the error that got urped out to the console but it was too big to fit into a SO post.

Comment: Put it somewhere else then like [here](https://gist.github.com) or [there](https://pastebin.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried various combinations and finally got it working again.

The last combo I did was:

1) Clean
2) Clean Build Folder
3) Quit Xcode
4) Deleted the app within the simulator
5) Shut down the simulator
6) Restarted the machine

After restart, I opened Xcode and was able to compile as I had before.  If anyone else runs into this, I hope this helps.